# Get FileStore object for any given path

Tags: java, linux, macos, os-agnostic

Edit: I recognize that FileSystem.getDefault() will give me what I was looking for in my original question statement. I am attempting to use FileSystem.getFileSystem(URI) to get the FileSystem for **any** given path.

I am attempting to develop some code that will give me a java.nio.file.FileSystem object for a given path.

Here is some grossly simplified example code to give a better idea of what is being attempted:

```
public FileSystem getCwdFilesystem()
{
    URI cwdUri = null;
    String delimiter = "";
    try
    {
        _cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        cwdUri = new URI("file", delimiter + _cwd, null);
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException ue)
    {
        System.out.println("URI Creation failure on URI: " + _cwd);
        ue.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Filestore data for CWD: " + cwdUri.toString());

    return (FileSystems.getFileSystem(cwdUri));
}
```

Upon execution, an exception is throw on the last line of code:

```
Filestore data for CWD: file:/Users/redacted/Documents/Java%20Projects/ExampleCode
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/'
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkUri(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:92)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getFileSystem(FileSystems.java:217)
    at examplecode.FilesystemCapacity.getCwdFilesystem(FilesystemCapacity.java:54)
    at examplecode.FilesystemCapacity.main(FilesystemCapacity.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

When I make a small update to the delimiter variable:

```
String delimiter = "/";
```

I get a different error message thrown from the same place:

```
Filestore data for CWD: file://Users/redacted/Documents/Java%20Projects/ExampleCode
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authority component present
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkUri(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:73)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:92)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getFileSystem(FileSystems.java:217)
    at examplecode.FilesystemCapacity.getCwdFilesystem(FilesystemCapacity.java:54)
    at examplecode.FilesystemCapacity.main(FilesystemCapacity.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

Adding additional "/" characters to the delimiter simply gets me the first error message again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you add "./" as the delimiter?

Comment: No joy. Error message changes to "Path component is undefined".

Comment: you should use File.separator instead of delimiter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a reference I had previously missed [on the last page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/misc.html) of the NIO.2 document trail.

I wrote up some test code that gave me exactly what I needed:

```
    public void getPathFilesystem(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            URI rootURI = new URI("file:///");
            Path rootPath = Paths.get(rootURI);
            Path dirPath = rootPath.resolve(path);
            FileStore dirFileStore = Files.getFileStore(dirPath);

            printFileStore(dirFileStore, path);
        }
        catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printFileStore(FileStore filestore, String path)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Name: " + filestore.name());
            System.out.println("\tPath: " + path);
            System.out.println("\tSize: " + filestore.getTotalSpace());
            System.out.println("\tUnallocated: " + filestore.getUnallocatedSpace());
            System.out.println("\tUsable: " + filestore.getUsableSpace());
            System.out.println("\tType: " + filestore.type());
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `resolve`; the documentation indeed says that doing so is important, but it is a little obscure.